# Internacionalizar variable en controladores?

Tags: spring, controller, model-view-controller, servicio, internacionalización

Buenas, pues me gustaría internacionalizar una variable en un controlador.
Tengo un formulario en el cual relleno algunos datos y dependiendo de los datos que introduzco en el formulario quiero darle valor a una propiedad de la entidad que muestro el formulario.
Os pongo en situación, tengo un formulario de una entidad que es applicationFor(solicitud) en la cual el cliente puede meter una tarjeta de crédito y en caso de que esté caduca insertaria en la propiedad reasonWhy "su tarjeta ha sido cancelada" pero de forma internacionalizada.

Controlador que recibe el submit del formulario.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/enter", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "enter")
public ModelAndView enter(@Valid ApplicationFor applicationFor, BindingResult binding) {
    ModelAndView result;
    if (binding.hasErrors())
        result = this.createEditModelAndViewCreditCard(applicationFor, null);
    else
        try {
            this.applicationForService.enter(applicationFor);

            result = new ModelAndView("redirect:list.do");
        } catch (final Throwable oops) {
            result = this.createEditModelAndViewCreditCard(applicationFor, "applicationforcreditError.commit.error");
        }
    return result;
}
```

Aquí el servicio que atiende la petición que es donde hago el check de la tarjeta de crédito y meto en la propiedad reasonWhy lo que me gustaría internacionalizar:

```
public ApplicationFor enter(final ApplicationFor applicationFor) {
    Assert.notNull(applicationFor);
    Assert.isTrue(applicationFor.getStatus().equals("DUE"));
    ApplicationFor result;

    if (this.checkCreditCard(applicationFor.getCreditCard())) {
        applicationFor.setStatus("ACCEPTED");
        applicationFor.setReasonWhy("");
    } else {
        applicationFor.setStatus("REJECTED");
        applicationFor.setReasonWhy("Your credit card is expired");
    }
    result = this.applicationForRepository.save(applicationFor);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Te sugiero que leas acerca del componente [MessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) . Se usa para lo que preguntas. Si tienes problemas al usarlo puedes editar tú pregunta con el código que tengas.

Comment: Buenas compañero, la internacionalización a nivel de vistas sí la tengo implementada pero en este caso al ser a nivel de controlador pues no se como relacionar mi fichero message y message_es en el controlador.

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo la internacionalización ya implementada. En el controller puedes acceder a los mensajes de la siguiente forma:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

private void miFuncion(){
    Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    String reasonWhy = messageSource.getMessage("reason.why", new Object[] {}, currentLocale);  
}
```